# AngularJS and Directive Scope with Template not populating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am having issues working with direvtives and their scope. I've created a directive for getting all the members of a site and put them in a div, like so:

```
EngagementApp.directive('siteMembers', ['$compile', 'Request',
function($compile, Request) {

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : false,
        template : '<h4>Members {{name}}</h4><span class="view-all"><a href="/members">View all</a></span><ul><li ng-repeat="user in users"><a profile-modal="{{user.user_name}}" href="{{site_url}}{{user.user_name}}"><img src="{{site_url}}users/profileimage/{{user.user_id}}"></a></li></ul>',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.site_url = main_site_url;

            Request.get({
                url: 'users',
                data : {
                    fields : 'user_id, user_name',
                    conditions : {customer_id : current_site_id},
                    join : ['customer_users']
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    scope.users = response;
                }
            });


        }
    };
}]);
```

This works totally fine. Now I have another directive that populates a modal for user when clicked, like so:

```
EngagementApp.directive('profileModal', ['$compile', 'Request', '$modal', '$q','createDialog',
function($compile, Request, $modal, $q, createDialog) {

    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : false,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var modalPromise = null;
            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                scope.modal = {
                    username : attrs.profileModal,
                    url : main_site_url
                };

                scope.url = main_site_url;

                console.log(scope);
                createDialog({
                    id : 'profile_modal',
                    title : attrs.profileModal + " 's Profile",
                    template : '<iframe src="{{url}}{{modal.username}}?modal=true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;"></iframe>',
                    footerTemplate: '<button class="btn" ng-click="$modalCancel()">Close</button>',
                    backdrop: true,
                    css : {                     
                        height: '80%'
                    }
                }, scope);

            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

Here it where this mess up. The directive for the modal, when called from the members directive, never works. The temp;ate options {{url}} and {{username}} are empty.

But if I put the profileModal on another element that was not populated members directive(so it called first), it works.

Am I doing something wrong here with the scope or binding templates to scope?

Answer (score 1):

For the profileModal directive, try to specify the scope property like this (which I believe allows you to have the actual object and not the value):

```
scope: { user: "=" }
```

Then, in your template for the first directive, you can do something like:

```
<a profile-modal user="user" ...>
```

In your link function for the second directive, you should have access to scope.user and any other properties on that object and you can use them in template (i.e. user.userName etc)